# How to verify a typeof string inside a input value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a little project here, but I got stuck.

I want to defer how many letters and numbers I have inside my input value.

For example:

I put "1a2b3c" in the input, I want it to return: "you have 3 letters and 3 numbers".

The code I have here is pretty basic and it doesn't work

```
const botao = document.getElementById("btn")
const submit = document.querySelector("#texto");

function eLetra() {
  botao.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    for(let i=0; i < submit.value.length; i++) {
      console.log(i)
      if(typeof i !== "number") {
        console.log("string")
      }else {
        console.log("number")
      }
    }
  })
}

eLetra()
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` is the index, not a character in the `value`, it's always a number. You need to use `submit.value[i]` to get the corresponding character.

However, the type of the characters in a string are also `string`. You can't use `typeof` to distinguish letters from digits.

You can simply check if the character is between `'0'` and `'9'` to tell if it's a number.

```js
function eLetra() {
  botao.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    for (let i = 0; i < submit.value.length; i++) {
      console.log(i)
      if (submit.value[i] >= '0' && submit.value[i] <= '9') {
        console.log("number")
      } else {
        console.log("string")
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `regexp` and `match`

```js
const botao = document.getElementById("btn");
const submit = document.querySelector("#texto");

function eLetra() {
    botao.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let countNumbers = submit.value.match(/\d/g).length;
        let countLetters = submit.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).length;
        console.log(
            `You have ${countLetters} letters and ${countNumbers} numbers`,
        );
    });
}

eLetra();
```

```html
<input id="texto">
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep 2 counters to track the frequency of letters and numbers, then update them while looping over the characters in the input.

```js
const botao = document.getElementById("btn")
const submit = document.querySelector("#texto");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
function eLetra() {
  botao.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let nums = 0, letters = 0;
    for (const ch of submit.value) {
      if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') ++nums;
      else if (/[a-z]/i.test(ch)) ++letters;
    }
    output.textContent = `you have ${letters} letters and ${nums} numbers`;
  })
}
eLetra();
```

```html
<input id="texto">
<button id="btn">Check</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another method .. I like `parseFloat`.  You can check to see if it's numeric using `isNaN` (is Not a Number):

```
if( !isNaN(parseFloat(character)) ) {
```

And there really is no reason to do a complicated `for` iteration with `i` .. Just iterate through every character in your string natively, using `of`:

```
for(let character of string) {
```

..  No need for `.length` etc

```js
function eLetra(string) {
  
  let number = 0;
  let  letter = 0;  
  for(let character of string) {
    if( !isNaN(parseFloat(character)) ) {
        // console.log(character + " is a number");
        number ++;
    }else {
        // console.log(character + " is a string");
        letter ++;
    }
  }
 console.log(`You have ${number} numbers and ${letter} letters`)
}
    
eLetra('123ffff45');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and use `isNan` to determine is not valid number

```js
const botao = document.getElementById("btn")
const submit = document.querySelector("#texto");


  botao.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let number = 0;
    let text = 0;
    const textArray = submit.value.split("");
    for(let i=0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
      if(isNaN(textArray[i])) {
        text = text + 1;
      }else {
        number = number + 1
      }
    }
    console.log(`you have ${text} letters and ${number} numbers`)
  });
```

```html
<input id="texto" />
<button id="btn">
submit
</button>
```